# Security libraries in java

Tags: java, security

what security modules(DLLs) are available in java for common programming errors such SQl injection

while for  such DLLs in java i have found SQL injection can be prevented by PreparedStatement object in java so i need to know whether there is a library that can help me to do that

Comment: Java usually doesn't use DLLs to organize modules; that's a Windows-specific technology that would violate "write once, run anywhere."  Instead, Java uses JAR files.  That's not to say that the core Java runtime for Windows isn't organized using EXEs and other Windows-specific technologies, but you are looking for JARs rather than DLLs.

Comment: what is your target platform? Are you making a website or some sort of client / server app? There are many tools out there that can help you find vulnerabilities. Best way to prevent SQL Injection attacks is build you SQL query strings server-side

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there are any separate libraries that would clean your input automatically, it comes down to how you create your queries. [OWASP Wiki](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#Defense_Option_1%3a_Prepared_Statements_.28Parameterized_Queries.29) has some examples and tips on preventing SQL-injection, including some Java examples for Prepared Statements and Hibernate.

Answer (score 3):

In Java, you normally do not use DLLs directly. DLLs are Windows-specific native libraries. In Java, libraries are usually packaged as JAR (Java ARchive) files. There are thousands of open source Java libraries available on the web for almost anything that you'll ever need.

> SQL injection can be prevented by PreparedStatement object in java so i need to know whether there is a library that can help me to do that

You don't need a library, you just need to use `PreparedStatement` and set the values that you want to put into your sql statements through the `set...()` methods on the PreparedStatement instead of concatenating them into an SQL string yourself. The jdbc driver for your database will then automatically take care of escaping the values to prevent sql-injection attacks.